# Relation of pooled logistic regression to time dependent Cox regression analysis

Tags: logistic, cox-model

I found on [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2281238) paper (D'Agostino, et al. 1990) that pooled logistic regression is close to the time dependent covariate Cox regression analysis.

I would like to be able to reproduce estimates obtained from a pooled logistic model with those from a time dependent Cox regression analysis.

My data looks like this :

> A
>
> id age female time0 time1 death
>
> 1   1  20      0     0     1     1
>
> 2   2  21      1     0     1     0
>
> 3   2  21      1     1     2     0
>
> 4   3  19      0     0     1     0
>
> 5   3  19      0     1     2     1
>
> 6   4  22      1     0     1     0
>
> 7   4  22      1     1     2     0
>
> 8   4  22      1     2     3     1
>
> 9   5  20      0     0     1     0
>
> 10  5  20      0     1     2     0
>
> 11  5  20      0     2     3     0
>
> 12  5  20      0     3     4     0
>
> 13  6  24      1     0     1     0
>
> 14  6  24      1     1     2     0
>
> 15  6  24      1     2     3     0
>
> 16  6  24      1     3     4     1

I tried to fit these 2 models :

```
glm(death~ age + female, data= A, family=binomial)
coxph(Surv(time0,time1, death) ~ age + female, A)
```

Estimates of the 1st model are :

> Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
>
> (Intercept) -2.65425   12.06138  -0.220    0.826
>
> age          0.08814    0.61009   0.144    0.885
>
> female      -0.59971    2.17734  -0.275    0.783

Estimates of the 2nd model are :

> ```
>     coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z    p
> ```
>
> age    -0.140     0.869    0.622 -0.23 0.82
>
> female  0.156     1.168    2.121  0.07 0.94

I dont understand why I get very different estimates with the 2 models (I also had the same problem with different datasets). 
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The abstract to the paper states that the estimates are "close," not the same. It would aid potential respondents if you were to post the results from these models.